# Do we need LaTeX here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am quite new here, I noticed that there is not LaTeX here in Database Administrators, is there any reason for that? or maybe it will be better if we could use LaTeX. e.g to write stuff like that (Relational Algebra):
[image]

Thanks

---

EDIT: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a small taste about LaTeX power, making tables easly and many many more.

Comment: Why does it need LaTex? Are there any posts that need this special formatting?  I don't think I've ever seen a post on [DBA.SE] that would need this.

Comment: @bluefeet One case is illustrated in the picture - relational algebra. Questions that would benefit massively from this are fairly rare though, in my estimation.

Comment: @PaulWhite Ok, but is this being posted in questions/answers on the site enough to have this available?  I don't think I've seen any posts that this would be needed on. Maybe an example or two would be helpful.

Comment: Do any of the other SE sites have some sort of intrinsic LaTeX support?

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells Sure, Mathematics and also Computer science ,maybe more

Comment: If LaTeX support can be activated easily it might be a way to get tables to render on dba.se.

Answer (score 6):

**No.** I don't think we need LaTeX here.

- There aren't enough questions where it would be *necessary*.
- There is also the [page rendering overhead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/440595) to consider.

For very simple cases e.g. `πR(R ⋈ S)` as in my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117019/1192), the normal character set is adequate.

On the odd occasion where e.g. complex relational algebra is required, an image should suffice:

[image: Example]

The above was generated using [this tool](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), mentioned in this [meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164286/194636).

```
-- Source
\Pi_{A,B}(\sigma_{r.C=s.C})(r \times s)\otimes\sigma_{D > 20}(s))
```

*<sub>(That is my first ever effort at LaTeX formatting)</sub>*

There is also [mathurl.com](http://mathurl.com/) and probably many others.

If it were a "simple checkbox" to enable this for Database Administrators without *any consequences at all*, I'd probably say "yeah, OK, why not" but I don't think that is the case.

The case is clearly pretty compelling for sites like [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but not here.

To address a point brought up in a comment to the question, I don't think this is the solution for the 'tables' issue either (assuming for a moment that it is an issue). How many people that currently struggle with an ASCII table (or other workaround) would be able to generate the required LaTex? Not many, I would suggest.

Comment: It is hard to me to accept the answer because  I think that LaTex is needed, very nice answer though.

Comment: This could be turned on, however enabling MathJax comes with a heavy dependency. While [DBA.SE] isn't the size of sites like [so], there is a significant performance impact by enabling it. [Nick Craver wrote this up in detail on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/426671).  If the community wants it, we can still do it, you just need to be aware that there are issues.