# Can we enable MathJax on DBA.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Yes, this is related to the [question asked by Jack Douglas](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/934/please-can-we-have-markdown-tables-on-dba-se) over 4 years ago, and yes I did see that Adam Lear did update his (accepted) [answer](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/39083) to that question a few months ago, however I've got to question the approach it seems is currently being taken, as summarized in Adam's answer:

> My advice for now is to continue developing your script if you think it's necessary. Get it to the point where many people are using it, and we can see about integrating it into the site itself.

First off, I think the development of the community-driven functionality died with Jack's post 4 years ago.  Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but I've not seen nor heard of any table equivalent functions (in beta or otherwise) on the dba.se site.

Secondly, why wait on the re-invention of the wheel when you can just enable [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is being utilized on other .SE sites ([Math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question/) | [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22229/why-is-the-tu-95-so-efficient-despite-having-propellers-that-spin-faster-than-th))?  I understand that we're using a different markdown parser, [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/), but does this have any functionality conflicts with the MathJax commands?  If not, this seems like a quick win.

Finally, the issue that MathJax is difficult to learn is a bad answer.  I'm not saying it's easy, but if people don't want to use the syntax, they're not being forced to do so.  I'm not asking we make people use it, I'm just asking we enable MathJax (so long as it's compatible with the current site) and provide an option for people that do want to include this sort of formatting in their questions and answers.

Comment: Related https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2465

Comment: @PaulWhite Buried in there is your link to [this answer about page rendering speed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/944748), which sounded like a good reason until I read this in Nick Craver's answer: "These are the numbers for the **first visit (uncached) views** of the homepage... ... We're talking about a 21.3% increase in page load time for a user **first hitting the site**."  This is about a single page load once per user, which again, seems like a very small premium for added functionality.  I am admittedly a layman regarding websites, but even then...

Comment: Yep I don't really have much of an opinion either way. My answer on the related item was there to *make the case* that it was unnecessary.